# Allow jquery ui slider handles to cross over when range is true

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

How do I allow the slider handle with range option true to cross over each other

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#slider").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        values: [10, 90],
        slide: function(event, ui) {

        }
    });
});
```

The following jsfiddle has example of both sliders with range set to true and one without range,I want the one with range set to true behave in similar manner as the other one

http://jsfiddle.net/w4gy8p1v/1/

Comment: I don't know of a slider that allows handles to overlap, but one may exist (research-research). The standard approach would be to use two sliders, each with a single handle.

Comment: @Roamer-1888  can you please go over the question once again I have modified it after you commented,see if you can help any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: I understand better what you mean now but I don't think it's simple to achieve what you want with the jQuery UI slider. With "range:true" the handles won't cross over; and with "range:false" you don't get the orange highlight. It would take a lot of effort to merge the two.